# How to make UIBarButtonItem give menu-options?

Tags: iphone, hyperlink, uibarbuttonitem

You know how if you click and hold on a link in Safari (for iPhone obviously) it gives you a list of options like "open in new window", "Open". "Copy" etc?

How do you call this and is it possible to get a UIBarButtonItem to do this (but every time it is clicked not just when held down)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you show this menu:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                         delegate:self 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel", 
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Button 1", @"Button 2", @"Button 3", nil];
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;

[actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
[actionSheet release];
```

In order to connect it to `UIBarButtonItem` just point the bar button item to a selector that will include the code above.

Don't forget to implement `- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` method of `UIActionSheetDelegate`.